# .htaccess RewriteEngine and Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess

```
namesite.com/+54500
namesite.com/+55806
namesite.com/+90094
namesite.com/+.....
```

Есть ссылки, которые начинаются с +, а затем идет число, скажите как правильно перенаправить, если в начале ссылки указан + (ПЛЮС), то нужно сделать редирект?

Если (`namesite.com/+.....`) тогда перенаправить на `http://www.google.com`

Как прописать условие в файле .htaccess, если в ссылке после слэша скажем есть +, то сделать редирект на http://www.google.com?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow *in Russian*... Здесь принято общаться на русском языке, так что прошу вас перевести вопрос. )

Comment: Oleg, а что именно у вас не выходит? (ведь примеров/руководств/пособий/статей/книг по этому поводу в интернете — более чем достаточно).

Comment: Не получается работающего способа, вот и прошу помощи...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант реврайта с обнаружением плюса в начале:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/\+
RewriteRule .* https://www.google.com/ [R,L]
```

P.S. Хотя всегда думал, что плюс в пробел преобразуется на сервере.

Comment: Спасибо, работает...